# Ansible: ios_config - want to remove a configuration line only if it exists

Tags: networking, routes, ansible, yaml, cisco

I need to remove the IP SLA configuration on the router if it is currently running via "no ip sla 46" but, if it doesn't currently exist on the router, the playbook fails. Ideas?

```html
    - name: Add IP SLA test
      ios_config:
        lines:
          - udp-jitter 10.x.x.x source-ip {{ loopback }} codec g711ulaw
          - tos 184
          - tag Network Operation Center - G711ulaw EF VoIP
          - frequency 180
        parents: ip sla 46
        before: no ip sla 46
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using ios_command to check for a current IP SLA config and delete if present.

```yaml
- name: Find current SLA 46 config
  ios_command:
    commands: 'show run | inc sla 46'
  register: raw_sla_46

- set_fact:
    sla_46: "{{ raw_sla_46.stdout[0] }}"

- name: Delete IP SLA 46 if present
  ios_config:
    lines:
      - no ip sla 46
  when: sla_46 == 'ip sla 46'

- name: Add IP SLA from Lo0 to DC
  ios_config:
    lines:
      - udp-jitter 10.20.0.25 17000 source-ip {{ loopback }} codec g711ulaw
      - tos 184
      - tag Network Operation Center - CHA - G711ulaw EF VoIP
      - frequency 180
    parents: ip sla 46
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem - I want to change the NTP servers but in the interest of idempotency when I add the ones I want, I want to remove any that were old/erroroneous. In ansible there should be a way that I can just replace the lines - I don't want to use the before clause to remove all the ntp config because it has destructive side affects.

current config

```
ntp server 10.10.10.10
```

desired config

```
ntp server 10.10.10.20
```

If I run a playbook with the ios_config command for the new server I end up with 2 NTP servers - which isn't what I want!

Answer (score 0):

This task should allow you to run a 'show run command' and then if results are found will attempt to remove it from the config.  If nothing is returned from the show command, the tasks are skipped.

```
---
- name: Show command
  cisco.ios.ios_command:
    commands: 
      - "show run | inc <filter>"
  register: output

- name: Prep
  # Prepend 'config t' & prepare lines for removal
  set_fact:
    remove_lines: "{{ ['config t'] + output.stdout_lines[0] | map('regex_replace', '^', 'no ') }}"
  when: output.stdout[0] | length > 0

- name: Remove lines from config
  ansible.netcommon.cli_command:
    command: "{{ remove_item }}"
  loop: "{{ remove_lines }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: remove_item
  changed_when: true
  when: output.stdout[0] | length > 0
```